# install tensorflow 2.1 via pip

Tags: python, tensorflow

Some code asks me to install TF2.1 but that version doesn't seem to be available.

```
ImportError: This version of TensorFlow Probability requires TensorFlow version >= 2.1; Detected an installation of version 2.0.0-alpha0. Please upgrade TensorFlow to proceed.
dnachbar@dnachbar1:~/python/tfp$ python3 -m pip install tensorflow==2.1
Collecting tensorflow==2.1
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==2.1 (from versions: 1.13.0rc1, 1.13.0rc2, 1.13.1, 1.13.2, 1.14.0rc0, 1.14.0rc1, 1.14.0, 2.0.0a0, 2.0.0b0, 2.0.0b1)
No matching distribution found for tensorflow==2.1
```

Comment: Can you try to update pip first, and try again? 
```pip install --upgrade pip```

Answer (score 0):

What version of Python are you using?

Note that tensorflow is currently only provided for Python up to v3.7, see https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow/